# How to fix accentuation encoding with cmd.exe running inside bash?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd.exe, encoding, character-encoding

I installed https://www.msys2.org/ and setup an [ssh server](https://gist.github.com/samhocevar/00eec26d9e9988d080ac) for it. With this I can connect to my machine and work remotely. The problem is that some application as Visual Studio tools or windows specific `cmd.exe` programs cannot run from a `bash.exe` shell. Then, I nest a `cmd.exe` shell inside my `bash.exe` shell to run these applications (I also use `winpty.exe` for mapping the input arrow keys https://github.com/rprichard/winpty).

The problem with this setup is that accentuated letters are displayed as `_`, for example, running the command `cp -h`, I triggered an error which showed a message where the word `informações` was displayed as `informa___oes`:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. I know my `cmd.exe` console uses the encoding `850` because when I run `chcp` in a new shell, it outputs `850`. I tried changing its value to `1252` and `65001`, but it keeps showing accented letters as `_`:

[image]

I searched for this 850 encoding and I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850, where it is called as `DOS Latin 1`. Would this problem be fixed if I set my bash encoding to `DOS Latin 1` before I nest a `cmd.exe` command prompt inside it? How could I set my `bash.exe` encoding to this `CP 850` or `DOS Latin 1` encoding?